# SQLData with spring not working for Oracle SQL Procedure with complex oracle datatype

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures

In Oracle I have types like:

```
create or replace TYPE             "LOCATION_RECORD" AS OBJECT
( PSTL_ADR            ADR_TABLE
 ,GEO_CDE     VARCHAR2(36)
 ,PRMRY_FLG    VARCHAR2(5)
);

create or replace TYPE "LOCATION_TABLE" AS TABLE OF LOCATION_RECORD;
create or replace TYPE             "ADR_RECORD" AS OBJECT
( LN_1_TXT   VARCHAR2(100)
 ,LN_2_TXT   VARCHAR2(100)
)

create or replace TYPE "ADR_TABLE" AS TABLE OF ADR_RECORD;
```

Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE Main(P_LOCATION_TABLE      IN     LOCATION_TABLE    
              ,P_OUTPUT          IN     LOCATION_TABLE );
```

How can I call this procedure in java?  This is a special case where one oracle type table contains another 
oracle type table. 
I had tried with SQL data implementation. It was not working.
Only if oracle type record has no table type as one of its parameter then it works through java. 
BUT when one oracle type record has another table type as one of its parameter, it does not work. 
How to construct `STRUCT` array type of `LOCATION` table which also contains `ADR_TABLE`? How to get output parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext/)

The convenient class for you is `SqlStructArrayValue`, where `arrayTypeName` is your `LOCATION_TABLE`, structTypeName - `LOCATION_RECORD`. And `StructMapper` implementation should correctly populate a `StructDescriptor` for your values.

Right, in this case you should use `SqlStructArrayValue` as nested object one more time, because your `PSTL_ADR` is an `ARRAY` too.

See the source code of that project and test-cases from there.